# Opening cache files in Hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

After adding a cache file to a job with `job.addCacheFile()` and pulling it down with my mapper with `context.getCacheFiles()`.  How can I open the cache file.  I've tried using:

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));` (commented below)

where filename is the `toString()` of the `URI`, but I get an IOException saying the file doesn't exist.  Can anyone help me out?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.*;

public class UFOLocation2
{
    public static class MapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>
    {
        private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);
        private static Pattern locationPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{2}[^a-zA-Z]*$");

    private Map<String, String> stateNames;

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            URI[] cacheFiles = context.getCacheFiles();
            setupStateMap(cacheFiles[0].toString());
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println("Error reading state file.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] fields = line.split("\t");
        String location = fields[2].trim();

        if (location.length() >= 2)
        {
            Matcher matcher = locationPattern.matcher(location);
            if (matcher.find())
            {
                int start = matcher.start();
                String state = location.substring(start, start + 2);
                context.write(new Text(lookupState(state.toUpperCase())), one);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupStateMap(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        Map<String, String> states = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // the following line causes an IOException
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            String[] split = line.split("\t");
            states.put(split[0], split[1]);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        stateNames = states;
    }

    private String lookupState(String state)
    {
        String fullName = stateNames.get(state);
        return fullName == null ? "Other" : fullName;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(config, "UFO Location 2");
    job.setJarByClass(UFOLocation2.class);

    job.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/kevin/data/states.txt"));

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    Configuration mapconf1 = new Configuration(false);
    ChainMapper.addMapper(job, UFORecordValidationMapper.class, LongWritable.class, 
                Text.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, mapconf1);

    Configuration mapconf2 = new Configuration(false);
    ChainMapper.addMapper(job, MapClass.class, LongWritable.class, 
                Text.class, Text.class, LongWritable.class, mapconf2);

    job.setMapperClass(ChainMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);               
}
}
```

Is this a code issue or a configuration issue?  I'm running on a supposedly psuedo-distributed cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
    Path path = new Path(uri[0].getPath().toString());
    if (fileSystem.exists(path)) {
        FSDataInputStream dataInputStream = fileSystem.open(path);

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while (dataInputStream.read(data) > 0) {
            //do your stuff here
        }

        dataInputStream.close();
    }
```